# What is the most efficient way to subtract rows of a dataframe (python pandas) by index in python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe pandas like this:

```
cEventID    arrivalTime
1167533 
1167541 2015-07-14 04:01:21
1167545 2015-07-14 04:03:20
1167549 2015-07-14 04:07:45
1167552 2015-07-14 04:10:21
1167553 2015-07-14 04:13:39
1167558 2015-07-14 04:15:58
1167561 2015-07-14 04:20:23
```

and I need to subtract the time between one event and another, the result would:

```
EventID arrivalTime diff time
1167541 2015-07-14 04:01:21 0
1167545 2015-07-14 04:03:20 00:01:59
1167549 2015-07-14 04:07:45 00:04:25
1167552 2015-07-14 04:10:21 00:02:36
1167553 2015-07-14 04:13:39 00:03:18
1167558 2015-07-14 04:15:58 00:02:19
1167561 2015-07-14 04:20:23 00:04:25
```

I get this result with a for loop about pandas dataframe with ***for index, row in datos.iterrows():***. My function is:

```
def llegadas(datos, estacion):     
    datos = datos       
    lista = []
    filas = []
    segundos = []
    for index, row in datos.iterrows():
        if index == 0: 
            lista.append('00:00:00')  
            filas.append(row)
        else:
            ii = filas[len(filas)-1][6] 
            ff = datos['arrivalTime'][index]
            deltat = str( dt.datetime.strptime(ff, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - dt.datetime.strptime(ii, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') )
            lista.append(deltat)
            filas.append(row)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(lista)
    frames = [datos, df1]
    datos = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
    datos.rename(columns={0:'dif_tiempo'}, inplace=True)
    return datos
```

Please suggest a way to make function more efficiently.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
In [4]:
df['diff time'] = df['arrivalTime'].diff().fillna(0)
df

Out[4]:
   cEventID         arrivalTime  diff time
0   1167533                 NaT   00:00:00
1   1167541 2015-07-14 04:01:21   00:00:00
2   1167545 2015-07-14 04:03:20   00:01:59
3   1167549 2015-07-14 04:07:45   00:04:25
4   1167552 2015-07-14 04:10:21   00:02:36
5   1167553 2015-07-14 04:13:39   00:03:18
6   1167558 2015-07-14 04:15:58   00:02:19
7   1167561 2015-07-14 04:20:23   00:04:25
```